# Rename [angular-cdk-virtuall-scroll] to [angular-cdk-virtual-scroll]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[angular-cdk-virtuall-scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cdk-virtuall-scroll) is misspelled: there is an extra "L" in "virtual".

Comment: You were given bad advice in now-deleted comments. Spamming the site with a non-trivial number of edits that do nothing more than fix the spelling of a tag is a **bad** idea. A moderator can rename with a few clicks, without bumping all the questions.

Comment: @CodyGray See that's exactly what I thought... This isn't my first tag edit request, but it seemed to gain traction. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yeah… the tag management features available to regular community members leave a lot to be desired. The unfortunate consequence is that well-meaning users try to take matters into their own hands, using the editing feature that is available to them. Editing is good, as far as it goes, but blasting the site with trivial edits can be very disruptive. Unfortunately, getting this message out to all Meta users has proven very difficult. Several of the moderators are very active in monitoring and implementing these retag requests. They’re not ignored.

Comment: @CodyGray Without digressing overly: I've almost never felt ignored by mods. Just wanted to do my part, if possible, because I know mods must be rather busy, to say the least, on this site ;)

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know if my idea was that bad and if yes, sorry for that. However, I didn't think of it as 'spamming edits', but as a chance to improve the 9 questions that were tagged incorrectly as the OP had to go through all the questions and fix all the posts mistakes.

Comment: @double-beep It's because it bumps all those posts to the front page.

Comment: So, what? Posts will be bumped; if they are bad, they will be closed, that's good for them. I don't think it is that bad to go through 9 questions only and retag them.

Comment: What exactly is a non-trivial number of edits?  IIRC there were only 9 questions with the misspelled tag.  As fast moving as the front page is (#50 by newest questions is only 5 minutes old right now); as long as the edits weren't done as quickly as possible (tag edit only) I wouldn't have thought it would be enough edits to cause a problem.